# What are the current sites that questions about warfare & military technology are on-topic and asked & answered with some regularity?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

In a series of comments under [What "whizzy new tools" in space are America and its allies using to track China’s military activity and illegal fishing? (The Economist)](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/80926/16047) (closed as off topic and I don't disagree) I wrote

> There are two SE sites that we don't have yet but I think would thrive - Optics & Photonics (those questions get spotty answers at best in Physics SE) and War & Military Technology SE.

and later

> Since there is so much information available on modern (and older) military equipment and its capabilities, and who's buying what, as well as the outcomes of military conflicts, I think there's certainly a large, rich fact base out there from which a Warfare & Military Technology SE site could draw questions and answers. Right now Politics, History, and a tiny corner of Space SE is where war can get a foothold in Stack Exchange, and since has such a huge footprint and impact on the real world, it could easily keep its own site active.

I'm wondering how accurate my impression is that "Politics, History, and a tiny corner of Space SE is where war can get a foothold in Stack Exchange". Perhaps there's more I don't know about, so I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What are the current sites that questions about warfare & military technology are on-topic and asked & answered with some regularity?

I don't mean any question would be on-topic, but *some of them at least can be*.

One way to start would be to check sites (via SEDE) that have tags that contain fragments like [*military*] and [*war*] that have regular activity. Another might be personal experience.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Longtime History mod here. I've had the sad duty of counseling users on possible alternate sites for their off-topic questions. I've also hung out a bit on a lot of related sites, so I know a bit about what's adjacent to us.

We do field a lot of military questions on [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/). However the example one here I'm certain would be closed as off-topic. A general rule of thumb for History is that *if your question doesn't use past-tense verbs, it's probably off-topic*.

Another option for historical military technology is [History of Science and Math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). They are arguably a proper subset of History (so anything on-topic there is on-topic on History too), but the users there are experts on things most History users would have to research. So if your question is on-topic there, its probably the best place to ask.

If the question is about hand-to-hand fighting, one option not a lot of people seem to know about is [Martial Arts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/). I've seen that site produce good answers for questions about the mechanics of Medieval European combat.

If the question is about military aircraft, [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) fields some of those. I see an open question there right now about [engine flameouts on MiG-31's](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/100569/why-do-the-engine-of-mig-31-spit-out-flame-when-going-for-afterburner)

Similarly, [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/) fields questions about satellites.

I've never been on [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), so I have no real-world experience there, but it seems like the example question ought to fly there, if (reading from [their Help Center](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) it can be made to seem a bit less of a "question that invites open-ended discussions or polls". Perhaps consider reading through their [questions tagged military](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) to get an idea what has been done there in the past and how it was recieved.

If the question is speculative, there's likely a way to formulate it which would make it on-topic on [WorldBuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

If it's neither speculative nor using past-tense verbs, and doesn't fit the narrower technical niches of the other sites I mentioned, then I'd put it on [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) and pray. I'm not a *regular* regular there, but I've seen questions about current [military strategy in the Russo-Ukranian war](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80957/why-did-ukraine-mobilize-a-relatively-small-number-of-soldiers-for-the-war) stay open and get good answers.